# Exclude IDs from PHP foreach loop

Tags: php, select, foreach

I am trying to exclude more than one ID from a select list that is populated by a foreach loop:

```
$types = new Type();
$types->where('id !=', 13)->order_by('name')->get();
$data['types'] = $types;

<select class="styled" name="form[type_id]">
<option value="0"> - select one - </option>
<?php foreach ($types as $t): ?>
<option value="<?=$t->id?>" <?=check_selected($t->id, $i->type_id)?>><?=$t->name?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<option value="13" <?=check_selected(13, $i->type_id) ?>>Other</option>
</select>
```

So at the moment it will exclude ID 13 (and add it manually to the bottom), but how do I add more IDs to be excluded?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
...
$exclude = array(13,25);// add IDs to exlude
....
<?php foreach ($types as $t): ?>
   <?php if(!in_array($t->id, $exclude)){ ?>// if the ID is in the exlude array don't add it
      <option value="<?=$t->id?>" <?=check_selected($t->id, $i->type_id)?>><?=$t->name?></option>
   <?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
...
```